# How to add standard deviation bars in ggplot stacked bar plots and reorganize order of data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to improve my grouped bar plot, and am trying to add standard deviations to each bar, but I seem to be struggling. Furthermore, I'd like to have the "pre-contrast" group left, and "post-contrast" group right, with "control" left and "anti-cd47" right within each respective group.

Here is my plot:

[image: Plot]

Here is my code:

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

t2<- read_excel("t2quant.xlsx")
summary(t2)

head(t2, n=12)


ggplot(data=t2, aes(x = Time, y = T2Value)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red', 'black'))+
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Group),
  width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width=0.7), stat="summary", fun.y = "mean")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0,20))
```

and here is my data, from dput:

```
structure(list(Time = c("Pre_Contrast", "Pre_Contrast", "Pre_Contrast", 
"Pre_Contrast", "Pre_Contrast", "Pre_Contrast", "Post_Contrast", 
"Post_Contrast", "Post_Contrast", "Post_Contrast", "Post_Contrast", 
"Post_Contrast"), Group = c("Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Anti_CD47", "Anti_CD47", "Anti_CD47", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Anti_CD47", "Anti_CD47", "Anti_CD47"), T2Value = c(14, 
10.4, 11, 16.7, 15, 12, 6, 5.8, 6.5, 3.5, 3.7, 2.6)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Group", "T2Value"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Is there some way I can add standard deviation to the data set via mutate or something? Or would I have to rearrange the data in my excel sheet in a completely horizontal fashion, as below?

Pre-contrast | control | data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | mean | SD |

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t2new <- t2 %>% 
    group_by(Time, Group) %>% 
    summarise(mean= mean(T2Value), sd = sd(T2Value))

ggplot(t2new, aes(Time, mean, fill=Group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-1.96*sd, max=mean+1.96*sd), width=.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.7))
```

[image]